# Creating Bookmarklet Newsfeed

Tags: javascript, browser, rss, bookmarklet, feed

I have a bunch of Bookmarklets.

> Bookmarklets (or "Favlets") are snippets of Javascript code saved as a bookmark to
>   allow you to interact with webcontent on a per-click-on-the-bookmark
>   basis.

The problem is, the `<link>` tag requires a valid URI and does not allow to be

```
<link><![CDATA[javascript:alert('...');]]></link>
```

I tried different variations.

My goal is to provide an RSS feed people can subscribe to and dynamically have the most up to date Bookmarklets / Favlets everytime their browser pulls the feed.

Anyone knows how to realize this with stock instruments, or would I have to code a browser extension/plugin doing this?

Comment: Could you clarify? Are yo trying to create a Bookmarket which loads the last item of a feed?

Comment: @JulienGenestoux When you add a feed to Firefox or Chrome as a dynamic bookmark, it creates a folder containing the links of the feeds and updates those according to changes in the feed. I'd like this, but with Javascript bookmarklets instead of standard URLs.